# Binding ComboBox to Secondary Object

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, data-binding, telerik, domainservices

My page's data context is set to an Instance of a Project class and all of the other fields in the page are working properly. Each project has another class associated with it as a property. This represents data from another company that we are integrating into this page.
I am attempting to bind to this sub object's TypeID property. Here is a sketch of the objects.

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public ABCProject ABCProject { get; set; }
}

public class ABCProject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ABCProjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public ABCProjectType { get; set; }
}

public class ABCProjectType
{
   public int ProjectTypeId { get; set; }
   public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what my XAML looks like:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro" x:Name="ProjectTypeCombo"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectTypePickList}"
                                 SelectedValue="{Binding ABCProject.ABCProjectTypeId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 SelectedValuePath="ABCProjectTypeId"
                                 DisplayMemberPath="TypeName"/>
```

The pick list is being bound properly. The issue is that the selected value and selected value path don't seem to be binding as I get a blank combobox when the page loads.

Comment: What happens when you drop `SelectedValuePath="ABCProjectTypeId"` from the XAML? i.e. use the default path. The alternative seems to be use `SelectedValuePath="ABCProject.ABCProjectTypeId"` as that is the path to the property relative to a list entry. (sorry the nesting is giving me a headache:))

Comment: Tell me about it! But that didn't work as the SelectedValuePath is linked to the collection that fills the combobox, whereas SelectedValue is bound to the field in the object you wish to modify. It's the SelecteValue that seems to bee my issue (at least when talking about this project - I clearly have other issues;-) )